# Alarm notification keeps firing even if it is canceled from another activity

Tags: android, notifications, alarm

I set an alarm from activity A then in activity B I can delete and update the alarm set in activity A. Updating of alarm is working but delete doesn't, I've already tried some answer from here but nothing seems to work.

I set my alarms like this.

```
public void Alarms() {
    for(eventlist_model model:arrayList)
    {
        int id=model.getEvent_id();
        String type=model.getEvent_type();
        String date=model.getEvent_date();
        String time=model.getEvent_time();
        String note=model.getEvent_note();
        SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        try{
            String sched=date+" "+time;
            Date newSched=format.parse(sched);
            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar1.setTime(newSched);
            if (calendar1.before(calendar))
                calendar1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, events_receiver.class).setAction("Dog_alarm");
            intent.putExtra("type", type);
            intent.putExtra("note", note);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            PendingIntent dog1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            final AlarmManager alarm1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                alarm1.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), dog1);
            } else {
                alarm1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), dog1);
            }
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        }

}
```

then in activity B I use this to cancel the alarm

```
public void cancelTask()
{   int id=Integer.valueOf(eventid);
    Intent intent = new Intent(update_task.this, events_receiver.class);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent task = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarm.cancel(task);
}
```

But it doesn't work and Im stuck here. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: post your alarm update code

Comment: I don't think it you need to see the update part because its just the same as updating a data in sqlite db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation of [cancel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)) method of `AlarmManager`:

> ***void cancel (PendingIntent operation)***
>
> Remove any alarms with a matching Intent. Any alarm, of any type,
>   whose Intent matches this one (as defined by filterEquals(Intent)),
>   will be canceled.

It means if `intentA` detected to be equal with`intentB`, using `filterEqauls` Method, i.e.  `intentA.filterEquals(intentB)==true`, then `intentB` in alarmanger can be used to cancel `intentA` which already set inside alarmManager. 
[filterEquals](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)) documentation notices:

> **boolean filterEquals (Intent other)**
>
> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent
>   resolution (filtering). That is, if their action, data, type, class,
>   and categories are the same. This does not compare any extra data
>   included in the intents.

It means it `filterEquals` does not care to extras inside intents to compare them but other paramters like `Action` should be **exactly** the same.
In your case, you've missed to call `setAction` in cancellation intent.

So you should change your `cancelTask` method like this:

```
public void cancelTask()
{   int id=Integer.valueOf(eventid);
    Intent intent = new Intent(update_task.this, events_receiver.class);
    intent.setAction("Dog_alarm");//<--- this is missed
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent task = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarm.cancel(task);
}
```

Comment: thank you, took me a few hours to get it right it seems adding this line into the code task.cancel() made it work.